# Wordpress Options Page Theory Question

Tags: php, functions, theme-options

I created an options page and it is functioning perfectly, but I am not sure I understand **how** it functions. It's cool I got it to work but I was hoping someone could help explain *why* it works.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php

    add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_options');  

        function add_custom_options()
        {
            add_options_page('Custom Options', 'Slider Settings', 'manage_options', 'functions','custom_options');
        }


    function custom_options()
    {
    ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Custom Options</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>

    <input type="text" name="options_value" size="85" value="<?php echo get_option('options_value'); ?>" /> 

    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Store Options" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="options_value" />

    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Where are these values being stored? There's a reference to `options.php` but my theme doesn't have an `options.php.`       I am just trying to wrap my head around what I made to try and better understand it's logic; I am also curious if I went about it the right way. The option(s) I store are retrieved within the theme (image url for example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page). It's quite common to create a particular file with custom functions that will set options and option page and then you can implement them in your theme to make it easily cutomizable though admin panel.

Comment: I know how to make the options page, I was curious how it worked, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `options.php` in question is WordPress's [`/wp-admin/options.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/options.php) file. Your code's hidden `action` & `page_options` fields tell `options.php` what to do (`update`) and with what (`options_value`).

#### Reference

[Trac page for `options.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/options.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, makes more sense now. Many Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.